# Does the tryLock method call go in the try block?

Tags: java, locking

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock
ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock
```

For the two above classes do I call lock like this

```
try {
     readLock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     [...]
} finally {
     readLock.unlock();
}
```

OR

```
readLock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
try {

     [...]
} finally {
     readLock.unlock();
}
```

Which is safer, and does the same apply to the `lock()` method versus the `tryLock()` method?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950078/threads-why-a-lock-has-to-be-followed-by-try-and-finally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to go in the conditional section, You can't attempt to use the data if you failed to get the lock.

```
if (readLock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    try {

         [...]
    } finally {
         readLock.unlock();
    }
} else {
    // failed to get lock
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What @PeterLawrey says, but there is more critical yet.

The [javadoc for `Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) says:

> A Lock implementation may be able to detect erroneous use of the lock, such as an invocation that would cause deadlock, and **may throw an (unchecked) exception** in such circumstances.

If you try and lock in the `try` block, you may end up in a "double trouble" situation, where you throw one exception in `try` and another in `finally`, since the lock will have failed to lock in the first place...

This essentially means that you must also `.lock()` normally in front of `try` blocks for this reason:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    something();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```